# Where does codeigniter create and destroy mysql connection and is the db class singleton?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If we have multiple `database groups` in database.php:-

1) Do the connections of all of them are made even only one has to be used in a particular call. ie. if i have database groups a,b
And in my call i load model that is loading only group b.

2) If i have loaded two models in my controller and if both of them are loading same databases, would different connection will be made or same connection will be shared.

Ex:- controller mycont.php has following:-

```
$this->load->model('model1');
$this->load->model('model2');
```

If both model1.php and model2.php has following:-

```
$this->load->db('connection_name');
```

3) Where are the connections closed.

Ex:- If i have following code:-

$this->databaseFunc();//completes the database work nothing required after this
  here a curl call is made which takes long time

So when does database connection is closed, after curl or it gets closed itself on over exceeding `mysql_wait_time configuration` at `mysql server`.

Hope the answer to this question will prove useful for understanding DB with codeigniter in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In CI, each library is a singleton. It is created on load->library and destroyed at the end of the request.

The database lib handle database connection, so the connection is closed when the library is destroyed. It has nothing to do with curl.

I've never tryed it but it should work like that.